# JTable how to fire event selecting a row or double click on a row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double-click

I'm using a javax.swing.JTable to show rows in a database table.
I need to fire two different event for two different cases:

- when is selected at least a row (or a click on at least a row is performed).
- when a double click on a row is performed.

I already looked for an answer on stack overflow, but I didn't find anything satisfying .
Any idea?

Comment: 1- Use the tables `ListSelectionModel` by attaching a `ListSelectionListener` to it; 2- Use a `MouseListener` on the `JTable` and monitor for a double click, presumably with the left mouse button. You may also want to do describe what solutions you've looked at and why they don't suit, so we don't cover the same ground and waste each other's time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when is selected at least a row (or a click on at least a row is performed).

You should monitor changes to the row selection using the `JTable`s `ListSelectionModel` via a `ListSelectionListener`.  This will notify you when the selection is changed by the user using the mouse or the keyboard or if the selection is changed programmatically for some reason

See [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more details

> when a double click on a row is performed

The only way you can detect this is through a use of a `MouseListener`.  Normally, users expect that a left mouse button click will do one action and the right mouse button will do something else.

You will want to use [`SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isLeftMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) or [`SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isRightMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) to determine what the user is actually doing.

See [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mouse listener to the table and capture event over there with mouse event like below

```
table.addMouseListener
      (
        new MouseAdapter()
        {
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
          {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
            {
            }
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1)
            {
            }
          }
        }
      );
    }
```

and to capture selection event you can use

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...);
```

Comment: So if I double click with the right button, this will trigger the your `if` statements.  What if I change selection with the keyboard?

Comment: @MadProgrammer need to add keyListener as well to monitor change selection with keyboard

Comment: Ahhh, no, `KeyListener` is not the answer, selection changes can occur for reasons other then key actions

Comment: @MadProgrammer you mean only ListSelectionListener can solve the purpose?

Comment: `ListSelectionListener` is the best choice for monitoring changes to the table's row selection, it will take into account changes by the mouse, keyboard and program itself...